# How To Access a SOAP WebService From a Flex Library Project

Tags: apache-flex, web-services, soap, air

I would like to access a soap webservice from a class in a Flex (AIR) Library Project.

How can I instantiate a WebService and get data from a SOAP WebService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [WebService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/soap/mxml/WebService.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) class.

More info here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdb.html